# mysql - my.ini server-id variable won't change

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-error-1064, database-replication

I want to set up replication on mysql.

I replaced the contents of the my.ini file in the slave with the following contents:

```
[mysqld]
log-bin = mysql-bin
server_id = 2
server-id = 2
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
sync_binlog = 1
replicate_do_db = replica
```

I don't know, the correct "server_id" or "server-id", so I wrote both of them. Then I save and I restart my mysql. Then I check with the command:
show variables like 'server_id'
then the output appears:

```
+ --------------- + ------- +
| Variable_name | Value |
+ --------------- + ------- +
| server_id | 1 |
+ --------------- + ------- +
```

I'm confused, why is the result 1? Then I try again with the command:
show variables like 'server-id'
then the output appears:
Empty set (0.00 sec)

The questions are:

1. Which one is correct: "server_id" or "server-id"? (because I've tried both of them still can't)
2. why after I save the my.ini file with the above settings, the server_id variable remains unchanged?

note:
I have run the "stop slave" command -> "start slave" then "reset master", but the results remain the same.

Answer (score -1):

server_id is correct one

> The master and each slave must be configured with a unique ID (using
>   the server-id option). In addition, each slave must be configured with
>   information about the master host name, log file name, and position
>   within that file.

I'm assuming you're using binary log option for replication

So, going through manual (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-howto.html)
you'll definitely need to:

1. For master - ensure that binary logging is enabled, and configure a unique server ID
2. Each replication slave must have a unique server ID
3. Configure the slave with settings for connecting to the master, such as the host name, login credentials, and binary log file name and position (more details on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-howto-slaveinit.html)